# How Can I Fix CSS background-image?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

### I added URL to `background-image` in CSS file.
IE 7 shows the image properly, but IE11 changes to `background-image: none`. Do you know how to solve it?

```css
    .progress {width:450px; height:230px; background:url('../images/etc/progress.gif') no-repeat left top;}
```

In case.. ,
When I click a button for popup, IE11 Can't load Url , but IE 7 can load Url
But, In IE11 Debug mode, IF I enter  ' $(".~~").show()' , then load the image Url

Comment: Can you paste the code of this element into the comments so I can help you with this?

Comment: Please use standards when posting a question please provide the code so that other developers can replicate the issue and help you with the proper solution. :)

Comment: Add the full code so others can help you

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue. So that we can have a better understading of the issue and can have a test. With only the above description, we can't locate the issue. Thanks for your understanding.